# Suppressing operator precedence in Python

Tags: python

While solving problems on SPOJ, I came across a problem which required the programmer to evaluate an expression without using precedence. That means:

`2 + 3 * 6=30 and not 20`

Is there any way to do this?
Is there any library or inbuilt function for this?

Comment: Place an open parenthesis after each operator, and close them all at the end before using eval. But probably, the problem wants you to implement your own parser, where not having to deal with priority is a big facilitation.

Comment: @MatteoItalia What do you mean open parenthesis after each operator? Wouldn't that reinforce priority? Can you give an example?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the opposite (all the open parentheses at the beginning, closing each one before each operator); this would force the required priority. But again, the point of such an exercise is different, you shouldn't use eval & co., but implement your own simple parser.

Comment: Yes. I get your point. I think I will build my own parser. Makes much more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could do something like (2+3)*6, but that's ugly. I don't think there's a real solution for that.
Unless... You want to write your own function. It'd have to do something like this:

```
def functionname(strng):
    strng = strng.split()[::-1]
    startval = strng.pop()
    while len(strng):
        op = strng.pop()
        val = strng.pop()
        startval = str(eval(startval + op + val)
    return startval
```

This is not ideal either, but it's better than nothing I guess.